# How can I implement TimerTask when my class already extends a class?

Tags: java, timertask

I'm trying to create a task to run every 5th second, but how can I do this when my class

```
public class BlueSlime extends Slime implements Shootable, TimerTask
```

already extends one class?

Is there a different type of Task I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should a task know anything about the frequency at which it runs?

- Create your Task and make it implement Runnable.
- Create or use a separate Task Scheduler or [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
- Run the task with the scheduler.
- Profit

A task should describe the job that is to be run, *not the frequency at which that job is to be run*

Comment: So I'll do `Task t = new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            shoot();
            return null;
        }
    };` and then create a new class that handles the task?

Comment: I suggest some [reading matter on the Executor Service and how to use it](http://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks mate, figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Java v 5+:

[`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) excerpt:

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the
>   concurrency utilities therein is the [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) which
>   is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or
>   delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the
>   Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads,
>   accepts various time units, and **doesn't require subclassing TimerTask
>   (just implement Runnable)**. Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
>   with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.